# use a color lookup table with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I created a lookup color table in pygame (here just gray level):

```
LUT = np.empty([256,3],np.uint8)
for gg in range(0,256):
    LUT[gg,:] = [gg,gg,gg]
```

Then I want to call each value of this lookup table to fill a 3D pixel array from pygame from a 2D matrix, for example with noise:

```
screenWidth = 800
screenHeight = 480
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight), 32)

buffer = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(win)
I = (255*np.random.rand(screenWidth,screenHeight)).astype(int)
buffer = LUT[I,:]
```

In appearance everything seems right, I get a 3D pixel array, each value is what I expect. But this pixel array is not being displayed in the window "win" I created (it remains black). What puzzles me is that if I fill the same pixel array element by element:

```
for rr in range(0,screenWidth):
        for cc in range(0,screenHeight):
            buffer[rr,cc,:] = LUT[I[rr,cc],:]
```

Then it works fine, but it's a lot slower. I can find no difference between the pixel arrays filled by the 2 techniques (both are regular (800,480,3) unit8 array as I would expect). And if I display them with matplotlib imshow the image look fine in both cases. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Why do you pass 32 as argument to `set_mode` do you want the depth to be 32? If so, you should do `set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight), 0, 32)` as the second argument is for a flag

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Comment: I ended up using a different library so I have not checked if it works, but I assume it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested loop

> ```py
> for rr in range(0,screenWidth):
>        for cc in range(0,screenHeight):
>            buffer[rr,cc,:] = LUT[I[rr,cc],:]
> ```

can be substituted by:

```py
buffer[:,:,:] = LUT[I,:]
```

`buffer = LUT[I,:]` doesn't changes the element of `buffer`. The statement generates an new buffer and assigns the new array object to the variable `buffer`. The elements of `buffer` have to be set by slicing (see [numpy - Basic Slicing and Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)):

```py
lutBuffer = LUT[I,:]
buffer[:,:,:] = lutBuffer
```